# freeze only a fix and specific set of connections between two dense layers during training

Tags: deep-learning, keras, theano

I need to  freeze a set of connection between two hidden layers while training. Similar to dropout but instead of random, we have a specific set of connection that should be frozen for all the training epochs.Can anyone suggest any way to implement this with theano or keras ?

Comment: provide some code, so we get a sense of what you want to do.